# WPF RenderTargetBitmap black bars on right side and bottom

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to save an image from my WPF user control. It works but I got black bars on the right side and the bottom. If I change the dpiX (96) and dpiY (96) it works but when I maximize the window, it's wrong again (then a bit of the usercontrol is missing ).

This is how I save the image as bitmap:

```
Dim parentWindow As Window = Window.GetWindow(_Map)
Dim rtb As New RenderTargetBitmap(parentWindow.ActualWidth, parentWindow.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
rtb.Render(_Map)
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
Dim bp As New BmpBitmapEncoder()
bp.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb))
bp.Save(ms)
Dim saveMap As New Bitmap(ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height of the window are a bit larger than your UserControl because it includes the titlebar and borders. if you use the dimensions of your control instead it works fine:

```
Dim rtb As New RenderTargetBitmap(_Map.ActualWidth, _Map.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
```

I recommend you also make sure the control is layouted properly by calling `Measure` and `Arrange` with the current or desired size before rendering.

Additional size calculations may be neccessary if you are using the `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` properties of your control.

Btw: WPF always uses 96 DPI for size calculations so you shouldn't change that.